# using quotes on c# commands that send to cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, command

I've searched a lot about this but there's not any example for this specific situation.

I want to compress the directory written on the textbox (dirdes) and show the output on rich textbox (`_output`).

Instead of compressing the directory that written on the textbox, it compresses the bin directory.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dirdes1 = dirdes.Text;
    string strCmdText;
    strCmdText = "/C compact /c /s /a /i /exe:lzx '" + dirdes1 + " *'";
    Process lzx = new Process();
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    lzx.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    lzx.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    lzx.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
    lzx.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    lzx.Start();
    _output.Text = lzx.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Edit: I think this is a quote error. because directory must be like this `"C:\"` not like this `'C:\'`

Comment: Tell us what the value of `dirdes.Text` is. I don't see a bin directory.

Comment: Also post the result in `strCmdText`.

Comment: Open a cmd.exe window and try typing command directly into the window.  Try both single quotes and double quotes until you find the correct syntax.

Comment: this is a case of "quotation hell", have you tried to just invoke cmd.exe with this command string in PowerShell? Like typing `cmd.exe /C compact...` and then replace the C# variable with a sample path? The `$cmdstr` that works in PowerShell like `cmd.exe $cmdstr` should also work in C#

Comment: dirdes.Text example: C:\compress . I don't see a bin directory too idk why it's bahaving like this.

Comment: I don't think that this is the right syntax for COMPACT. _/S:dir_ In any case it is clear that your command works on the current directory. Then BIN folder while debugging

Comment: Try with _strCmdText = $"/C compact /c /s:\"{dirdes1}\" /a /i /exe:lzx";_

Comment: @roozbehS Even simpler, just escape the quote: "Some text \"text in quote\" rest of text"

Comment: Chr(34) doesn't work

Comment: I've tried this: strCmdText = $"/C compact /c /s /a /i /exe:lzx:\"{dirdes1}\" *";
but it outputs compact command help

Answer (score 0):

I mixed textbox names in GUI... This cost me 24 hours!
And I changed code a bit. NOW IT'S WORKING

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dirdes1 = dirdes.Text;
        string strCmdText;
        string locationAddress;
        string cdCommand;
        string doCompress;
        locationAddress = dirdes1;
        cdCommand  = "/C " + "cd " + locationAddress;
        strCmdText = "compact /c /s /a /i /exe:lzx";
        doCompress = "/C " + strCmdText + " *";
        Process lzx = new Process();
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        lzx.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        lzx.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        lzx.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @locationAddress;
        lzx.StartInfo.Arguments = doCompress;
        lzx.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        lzx.Start();
        _output.Text = lzx.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        showCommand.Text = doCompress;

    }
```

some variables are for testing things don't worry about them